# Fedora 17 postfix postgresql support

Tags: postfix, fedora, dovecot

I have been reading this :

http://wiki.dovecot.org/moin.cgi/DovecotPostgresql
I decide to use the postgresql instead of mysql

Is there anyone who is using dovecot with postifx running virtual users and using postgresql.

actually, i have these error message :  error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql

postfix doent support postgresql.

Thanks

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=455206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, only Debian based distros ship with a patch to get postfix to work with psql. Since you're using Fedora, you'll probably have to skip the RPM and install from source. You can alternatively use Alien to convert a DEB to an RPM, but I've no idea what sort of whackiness that would introduce into your setup.